# How to find out the exact model of resistor when it's not clear?

Tags: resistors

I have 2 resistors that I can not recognize them as their color. according to the board, they are

```
RK-45
RK-46
```

[image]

honestly I'm not sure about their health, so how to test them and

how to find out the the exact model of these resistors ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: They look fine to me, they've just got a little warm over the years. To know if they're ok you would need to know what value they should be and take them out of the board to use a multimeter.

Comment: Unsolder them, measure it. The "RKXX" is just a name, not a part number.

Comment: thnx for your reply, after this : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493079/how-to-fix-hitachi-projection-color I check the board and last week I saw black smoke from these two resistors so I think maybe resistors cause problem

Comment: More likely something else is broken which caused the resistors to get too hot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to repair a TV, you can usually find a repair manual online. The first thing to do is to type in the model of the TV with "service manual" or "repair manual" and see what you get (being careful, some of those sites are spam/virus related).

I was able to find your repair manual here: [Manualslib.com: Hitachi C43FD2000](https://www.manualslib.com/download/1425816/Hitachi-C43-Fd2000.html).

Schematics of the boards start on page 23, but if you go to page 126, you'll see a parts list:

[image]

It doesn't really help much since it doesn't have the value there, but if you look at the schematic on page 29, you can find RK45/46:

[image]

So these are 1S-3R3JB, 3.3 Ohm 1-watt resistors. The [specific model](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kamaya/RC1-23R3JB?qs=L3QzcrVjv96rkScWqAiqOg%3D%3D) is available on Mouser (although it says 1/2 watt), however there is no stock. You should be able to replace them with any 3.3 Ohm, 5% 1-Watt resistor (should try to get Metal Oxide ones, [like this one](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/KOA-Speer/MOSX1CT528R3R3J?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvmQ%252BOLa8n%2FM%252B0UaCTJS1OO%252BtFBEBydR4ioXysABVQEaQ%3D%3D)).

Before you go pulling apart your TV though, take a look at the calibration procedures on page 66, you may be able to adjust out the distortion.

The [resistor bands](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-4-band) should be Orange-Orange-Gold-Gold:

[image]

Comment: "doesn't have the value there" ... It may be cryptic, but surely that's what 3R3 is in the description.  It's definitely tricky to check the colours of old parts, but I'd surely compare against RK42 if that's not burnt-looking, as it's listed as the same value.

Comment: Yes, it's "in" the part number but you'll need to decode that and it takes some time to learn that "3R3" means "3.3", especially if you aren't used to working with resistor part numbers. What I meant is if you look at the parts above it, it clearly identifies the value.

Comment: You're right of course, I only understood 3R3 in the description after reading the answer on the diagram!